# How to retrieve hardware firewall logs via API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm wondering if there is a way to retrieve the Fortigate firewall logs, as also found in https://control.softlayer.com/devices/details//vlanFirewall as "reports", or any additional logs.

I can retrieve the updateRequests, so I can get a history of changes to the firewall ruleset linked to the user that performed that action.

Regards,
Ilias

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these steps:

1. Find the **`Vlan_Id`** that the firewall is associated:

   ```
   https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Vlan_Firewall/[Vlan_Firewall_Id]/getNetworkVlans

   Method: GET
   ```

The response should be something like this:

```
[
  {
    "accountId": 207800,
    "id": 204000,
    "modifyDate": "2012-06-18T14:11:22-05:00",
    "primarySubnetId": 420900,
    "vlanNumber": 1600
  }
]
```

Where: ‘"id": 204000’ is what we need

**References:**

[SoftLayer_Network_Vlan_Firewall::getNetworkVlan](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Vlan_Firewall/getNetworkVlan)

[SoftLayer_Network_Vlan_Firewall::getNetworkVlans](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Vlan_Firewall/getNetworkVlans)

2. To get the `Ip address` list associated to the above **`Vlan_Id`**, execute:

   ```
   https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Vlan/204000/getFirewallProtectableIpAddresses?objectMask=mask[ id,ipAddress]

   Method: GET
   ```

**References:**
[SoftLayer_Network_Vlan::getFirewallProtectableIpAddresses](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Vlan/getFirewallProtectableIpAddresses)

3. Finally, as `Control Portal`, select the `IP Address`(in my case `Ip_Address_Id = 54846700`) to get `Firewall Report`. We will execute the following:

   ```
   https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress/54846700/getSyslogEventsOneDay

   Method: GET
   ```

**References:**

[SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress::getSyslogEventsOneDay](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress/getSyslogEventsOneDay)

[SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress::getSyslogEventsSevenDays](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress/getSyslogEventsSevenDays)

I hope this information help you.